# Image sizes are incorrect when page is rendered in MS Edge

Tags: html, css, microsoft-edge

I added Instagram and Facebook links to the navigation menu of [this site](http://chaletsdesbouleaux.com/). On Chrome they are shown in an appropriate size, but the original image sizes are used in Edge, which looks insane

[image: MS Edge]

The markup for the social links is

```
<nav id="nav">
    <ul>
        <!-- other menu items omitted -->
        <li class="social-link">
            <a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/chaletsdesbouleaux">
                <img src="images/social/facebook-white.svg" alt="Facebook"/>
                <span class="menu-label">Facebook</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="social-link">
            <a target="_blank" href="https://www.instagram.com/chaletsdesbouleaux">
                <img src="images/social/instagram-64.png" alt="Instagram"/>
                <span class="menu-label">Instagram</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

And the CSS which restricts the size of the logos is

```
.social-link {
    width: 50px;
}

.social-link .menu-label {
    display: none;
}

.social-link img {
    position: relative;
    top: 5px;
}
```

What changes do I need to make so that the images are shown in the correct size on Edge?

It's difficult for me to resolve this by trial-and-error, because the only computer I have access to is a Mac, which I can't install Edge on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.social-link img {
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
  width: 1.3em; // <!-- this might help
}
```